# kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill the idle task on Vmware workstation 7

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-13.04, fedora10

I am trying to install ubuntu through vmware Work Station.The process is halting after throwing the error "kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill the idle task", I searched for the solution in forums, but they are of little help. Here is the enviroment that I am using.

My current OS: Windows 7 (64bit)

Ubuntu ISO: 12.04.3 desktop(64 bit)

VMWare Workstation: version 7.

And here is the stack trace. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Switching to a newer version of VMWare should solve the problem. (I only tried the current version of VMWare Player (6.0.1) - which works  -so I would assume that the current version of VMWare Workstation will work as well)

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue , ubuntu requires atleast 2 processors allocated to work , so click on setting and then system browse through processor and change the number of processor to 2 , hopefully this works